# Check view dependencies from snapshot database

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

I want to find all objects in which view from snapshot database is called in the database.
For objects created in the database, that is possible using View Dependencies option.
Is there any way to find that out for views created in snapshot database?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I'm assuming that you want to answer the question "what objects does the view reference?". You can find that with the following query:

```sql
select referenced_schema_name, referenced_entity_name
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies
where referencing_id = object_id('HumanResources.vEmployee');
```

Obviously replace `HumanResources.vEmployee` with your view (I used the venerable AdventureWorks2019 database as a test).